# Apache 2.4 "Require ip" not working for /server-status, /phpMyAdmin etc with VirtualHost directives added in httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, virtualhost, httpd.conf, namevirtualhost

I recently changed using the Event MPM in my Apache 2.4 installation, alongside PHP-FPM and FastCGI proxy, I hope that wasn't the reason for my problem. I also started working with name-based VirtualHost directives although I don't have multiple websites, Linux (specifically CentOS 7) is just a VM running behind NAT.

Before these changes, except the VM was still running behind NAT, it was working fine (at least I believe so, which I will explain later), but the "Require IP" is bothering me now.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/website/public_html
        <Directory /home/website>
                Allow from all
                Options +Indexes
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Location />
                # Allow Internal IPs
                Require ip 10.0.0.0/8
                Require ip 172.16.0.0/12
                Require ip 192.168.0.0/16
                Require ip 0.0.0.0/8
                Require ip 127.0.0.0/8

                # Allow Company IPs
                Require forward-dns broadband1.company.com
                Require forward-dns broadband2.company.com

                # Allow all IPs (comment it if disallowed)
                Require all granted
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

So when I put the web files under the `public_html` folder, it works great. Brilliant! But then, I installed phpMyAdmin and modified `phpMyAdmin.conf` under `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`, like below:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       # Allow Internal IPs
       Require ip 10.0.0.0/8
       Require ip 172.16.0.0/12
       Require ip 192.168.0.0/16
       Require ip 0.0.0.0/8
       Require ip 127.0.0.0/8

       # Allow Company IPs
       Require forward-dns broadband1.company.com
       Require forward-dns broadband2.company.com

       # Was here by default
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Unlike the above VirtualHost, this time, I didn't grant all IP addresses to have access to phpMyAdmin because it is extremely dangerous if they can break into the database with brute force.

Same applies to `/server-status` and `/server-info`, only specific IPs can have access to such pages and surely not `Require all granted`. But after we started using VirtualHost, they can access such pages so literally the "Require IP" section under phpMyAdmin.conf and the directives I created for /server-status and /server-info are not working properly.

Then I curiously tried and commented "Require all granted" from `httpd.conf` and see what happens and then phpMyAdmin is inaccessible as expected. So it looks like the "Require ip" is solely based on the VirtualHost. However, the other 3 pages are not mentioned under VirtualHost so I don't know what I have done wrong.

My question is: how to make that "Require ip" working again for phpMyAdmin and /server-status and /server-info? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: The last part in the last config should give you the clues needed for fixing the rest . "Order,,,,". "Deny from All" etc.

Comment: The last part in the phpMyAdmin config is for Apache 2.2 syntax if I remember correctly. And that's why we have two IfModules to distinguish them. It's already there by default and shouldn't need adjustments. If you can tell me what exactly you need me to do?